# Losing connection to server from several computers

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I have a PostgreSQL server running Oracle Linux. In my network I have several workstations each running different OS (Fedora, Ubuntu, Windows).
Every once in a while I lose connection from the several workstations to the server while other workstations can connect with no problem.
If I do `service network restart` from the server the problem is solved and everyone can work until the next time it returns.
Any clues?

Thank you,
Ben.

Comment: ive seen this with ip overlaps on a flat lan...  or possibly broken/multiple dhcp servers (network restart acquires new lease). is server dhcp'd?  more details are needed to help here.

Comment: the server use static ip. i checked and there are no duplicate ips if that was what you suggested.

Comment: Try to see what corrolation there is between the machines that lose access vs. The machines that do not.... ie. Bad switch?

Comment: @nandoP I'm sorry i didn't understand your advice, what do you mean by "see the corrolation"?